# Find the derivative of the function $y=(\ln x)^{x/3}$

Tags: calculus

Hello looking for some assistance with a homework problem I'm really stuck.

$$3(\ln(x))^\frac{x}{3}$$

Would really appreciate the help.

Currently: (constant)

$$3(\ln^\frac{x}{3}(x))\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$$

Comment: Hint: You can write $(\ln x)^{x/3}=\exp\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\ln\left(\ln x\right)\right)$, then apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(3\ln^{\frac{x}{3}}\left(x\right)\right)=$$
$$3\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\ln^{\frac{x}{3}}\left(x\right)\right)\right)=$$
$$3\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{\frac{1}{3}x\ln(\ln(x))}\right)=$$
$$3\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{3}x\ln(\ln(x))\right)e^{\frac{1}{3}x\ln(\ln(x))}=$$
$$3\ln^{\frac{x}{3}}(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{3}x\ln(\ln(x))\right)=$$
$$3\ln^{\frac{x}{3}}(x)\cdot\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\ln(\ln(x))\right)}{3}=$$
$$\ln^{\frac{x}{3}}(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\ln(\ln(x))\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

the result should be $$\log ^{\frac{x}{3}}(x) \left(\frac{1}{3} \log (\log (x))+\frac{1}{3 \log
   (x)}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$y=\{\ln(x)\}^{\frac{x}{3}} \Rightarrow \ln(y)=\ln[\ln(x)^{\frac{x}{3}}]=\frac{x}{3}\cdot \ln[\ln(x)]$

Then $\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x}{3} \cdot [\frac{1}{\ln(x)} \cdot \frac{1}{x}] +\ln[\ln(x)]\cdot [ \frac{1}{3}]$